# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in Xro_config.php on line 21

Tags: php, arrays, variables, syntax-error, parse-error

I have been puzzled by this weird problem and it got me stuck. Please take a look. May be a differnt eye wil catch the error. I have pasted the code below so you may see where the error occurs at line 21 ( 'consumer_key' => $this->get_consumer_key(),).

Thanks for your help in advance. Cheers :)

```
<?php
    class Xro_config {

        //Set to true to enable Oauth debugging
        protected $debug = true;
        // public, partner, or private
        protected $xro_app_type = "Public"; 

        /* 
        * Xero Calback URL
        */
        protected static $_oauth_callback = '';

        /*
        * Xero Signature keys
        */
        protected $signatures = array(
            // local
            'consumer_key' => $this->get_consumer_key(),
            'shared_secret' => $this->get_shared_secret(),
            // 'rsa_private_key' => '/[path]/[privatekey].pem',
            // 'rsa_public_key' => '/[path]/[publickey].cer'
         );

        protected static $_consumer_key;
        protected static $_shared_secret;

        /**
         * Sets the Oauth Callback URL. The Default is in an emptystring
         * @param string $URL
         */
        public static function set_oauth_callback($URL) {
            self::$_oauth_callback = $URL;
        }

        /**
        * Gets the oauth_callback
        */
        function get_oauth_callback(){
            return self::$_oauth_callback;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the Cusumer API KEys
         * @param string $consumerkey
         */
        public static function set_consumer_key($consumerkey) {
            self::$_consumer_key = $consumerkey;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the Cusumer API KEys
         * @param string $sharedSecret
         */
        public static function set_shared_secret($sharedSecret) {
            self::$_shared_secret = $sharedSecret;
        }

        /* 
        * Get Signature Keys 
        */
        function get_consumer_key(){
            return self::$_consumer_key;
        }

        function get_shared_secret(){
            return self::$_shared_secret;
        }
              }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize variables on the class constructor.

For example:

```
class Xro_config {

  protected $signatures; 

  public function __construct()
  {
   $this->signatures = array(
          // local
          'consumer_key' => $this->get_consumer_key(),
          'shared_secret' => $this->get_shared_secret(),
          // 'rsa_private_key' => '/[path]/[privatekey].pem',
          // 'rsa_public_key' => '/[path]/[publickey].cer'
       );

  }
}
```

Comment: i ended up with something exactly like this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `$this` when declaring variables. `$this` only exists in member functions of the class. You will have to initiate the variable in the constructor of the class.

**Edit**

It looks like you are using static methods/variables for everything else. I assume you want this to be static too. But since you can't initialize a varible with a function, and you aren't going to be calling a constructor you should probably turn the `$signatures` variable into a method:

```
<?php

 class Xro_config {
 ...
  protected static function signatures() {
     return rray(
       // local
       'consumer_key' => self::get_consumer_key(),
       'shared_secret' => self::get_shared_secret(),
       // 'rsa_private_key' => '/[path]/[privatekey].pem',
       // 'rsa_public_key' => '/[path]/[publickey].cer'
    );
  }
 }
```

Comment: I ended up going with the __construct initializer method you suggested. Thanks Jason.